# Warning when canceling an edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, inline-editor, safari

I noticed that when I click edit on a post, and then cancel without editing anything, the page now gives a warning

> You have started editing this post. Abandon this edit?

Even though I'm certain I didn't change a thing. Is this a bug? I'm fairly certain this warning didn't pop up in the past.

Edit: it happens only on some sites, not on others. It looks like it seems to happen only on sites where I've got more than 2K (i.e. my edits are applied immediately), could that be right? Can people check this?

Comment: You've still started the process of editing it, so surely this would be by design?

Comment: @Joe but it didn't use to happen. In the past, you only got the warning when you'd made actual changes.

Comment: Stupid, off-the-wall question; Could this occurring be correlated to which site(s) you might have Unicoin features enabled on?

Comment: Can't reproduce. What browser?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Good question, but no, I also tried sites where I haven't been Unicoining on at all. It does only seem to happen on sites where I have 2K rep (editing privileges).

Comment: Note that if you write something then delete it (so the final outcome is no change) you will get warning because *you started to edit*.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This happened for weeks already. I reproduced it on my Mac and iPhone (full site of course). I don't know why I haven't reported it before, probably because unicorns.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Also a good question. SeaMonkey and Chromium on a 64bit Linux and IE9 on 32bit Windows in a virtual box. And yes, I know that if I do actually make changes, I do get this warning, as expected. But by now I've tested it so many times that I'm pretty sure I'm not accidentally making changes by mistake before hitting cancel.

Comment: If you use Chrome latest stable version or IE11 you still face this problem?

Comment: @ShadowWizard This version of Chrome is really pretty stable. But I don't have IE11 here, sorry.

Comment: OK, confirmed it's a browser issue. While SeaMonkey isn't supported, the latest Safari on iPhone is, and when I cancel an edit on a question (only question, in answers it's working fine) I indeed get a warning right away even if I did not touch anything.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Can you tell me which browsers are supported? While I can understand that only the very latest versions are supported, the ones I've tested with _are_ the latest versions under Linux.

Comment: @MrLister only latest versions of main browsers. On second look it appears that SeaMonkey is close enough to Firefox so probably supported. Let's hope for a quick fix! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have good news and bad news.

The bad news is that this has been the case for a very long time *so long as you had inline editing privileges*.

The good news is that I'm pushing a fix to this for us inline editors. Should be live in rev 2014.4.4.2136 on meta and 2014.4.4.1527 elsewhere.

Comment: The really bad news are how come such a bug went unnoticed for so long? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know about you, but when I go to edit a post, I *mean it*. ;) (And if I give up, I just close the tab.)

Comment: Well, Anna, my fingers are fatter than yours so more likely to misclick such links. :D

Comment: @AnnaLear Good point, but it often happens that I see a question with gibberish, and I suspect it contains HTML tags that are not between backticks, so they come out invisible. Then I go edit, but there aren't any hidden HTML tags to be corrected; the question is just gibberish.

Comment: Anyway, yes, I should have noticed it sooner too. That must have happened ever since I reached 2k.